# Raspberry Pi camera module manual gain control

Tags: camera

Is there a way to set the Raspberry Pi camera module to manual gain control? I've looked in the option of `raspivid` and there seems to be nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [picamera's documentation](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/api_camera.html#picamera.camera.PiCamera.exposure_mode) - the package that provides a pure Python interface to the Raspberry Pi camera module for Python 2.7 (or above) or Python 3.2 (or above):

> Exposure mode 'off' is special: this disables the camera’s automatic gain control, fixing the values of digital_gain and analog_gain. Please note that these properties are not directly settable, and default to low values when the camera is first initialized. Therefore it is important to let them settle on higher values before disabling automatic gain control otherwise all frames captured will appear black.

and

> analog_gain
>
> Retrieves the current analog gain of the camera.

as well as

> digital_gain
>
> Retrieves the current digital gain of the camera.

indicate that gain settings are not settable by the user. `digital_gain` and `analog_gain` can only be used to read the value.

Maybe using the different `exposure_modes` can help to adjust exposure to different lighting situations.